# Limit entries of One2many Lines in odoo

Tags: odoo

How to limit entries of one2many in field to two lines

```
 sale_lines=fields.One2many('sale.order.lines','sale_id',string='Sale Lines',limit=2)
```

Tried this,but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set certain constraint using `_sql_constraints` or `api.constrains`.

For example in your case `len` of `sale_lines` has to be restricted under 2
So you can add following

from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError

```
@api.constrains('sale_lines')
def _check_sale_lines(self):
  for record in self:
    if len(record.sale_lines) > 2:
      raise ValidationError('Not more than 2 lines ')
```